# Trying to understand .data in mips and how to call the functions

Tags: assembly, mips

lets say if i have

```
.data
prompt1 .asciiz " string1 "
prompt2 .asciiz " String2 "

.text
main: 
     addi $v0, $0, 4
     lui  $a0, 0x1000  #this will give me prompt1
```

So how do i get to prompt2 and what the working behind it? Best if someone could explain it to me using lui and what the advantage or disadvantage vs using la.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MIPS, but those are labels and not functions.  You should be able to refer to their locations with the `la` instruction (Load address) like such: `la $a0, .prompt1` or `.prompt2` if that was what you were after.

`lui` is Load Upper Immediate: it loads the immediate 16 bit value in to the upper 16 bits of a register.  Thus `lui %a0 0x1000` is in C `register x = 0x1000 << 16 /* 0x10000000 */`.  So why does this exist? Why not just a "load immediate" instruction like this: `li %a0 0x10000000`?  Well, MIPS has 32 bit instructions and the first 16 of those are needed to encode the instruction name and the register to be used, so we can only use 16 bit immediate values.

To get a 32 bit value in to a register, such as (in C again): `register x = 0x10002000` we need two instructions, first load the upper bits (`lui %a0 0x1000`) and then the lower bits (`addi %a0, 0x2000).  So if .prompt1 is at address 0x1000000 and you can get there using`lui` then to get to .prompt2 you may need to add a 16 bit immediate value.

Comment: Ok,but i am also trying to understand how to use lui as my prof is trying to get us to use it. But i just really don't understand it and my lecturer notes are not clear, so i cannot refer to those notes.

Comment: Okay, I've added an explanation.  Your question wasn't really clear that you had to use `lui`.  You should edit your question to better reflect what you weren't clear on because that will be more helpful to others.

Comment: ok thank you, now i understand a bit better. How do i know what address is prompt2 stored at, if i have xspim will it show on the gui interface or is there a formula to calculate its position?

Comment: `.prompt2` will be stored at the address `.prompt2` and if you want to get it then you can use `la`.  If you want to hard code it then you'll have to calculate it.  If you know `.prompt1` is at address 0x10000000 (as seems to be the case) then `.prompt2` should be at 0x1000000A (10 bytes after, which is the length of .prompt1).  Of course there might be alignment issues (so it could be at 0x10000010 for instance). (Apologies if I missed a zero in some of those numbers).

Answer (score 1):

To get an address of a variable into a register you typically write this in MIPS assembly:

```
la $v0, prompt1
```

To then load its contents into a register you'd do (assuming you're interested in its first byte):

```
lb $v1, 0($v0)
```

And to store (to its first byte):

```
sb $v1, 0($v0)
```

Now, that `la` thing in `la $v0, prompt1` is a macro instruction, meaning there's no such real instruction in the CPU. It typically expands into the following two instructions that do exist in the CPU:

```
lui $v0, %hi(prompt1)
addu $v0, %lo(prompt1)
```

The first loads bits 31 through 16 of $v0 with bits 31 through 16 of the address of prompt1. The second loads the rest of the bits, 15 through 0.

So, if you look at the above la followed by lb closely enough, you'll see there are three actual instructions behind them:

```
lui $v0, %hi(prompt1)
addu $v0, %lo(prompt1)
lb $v1, 0($v0)
```

But you can do better:

```
lui $v0, %hi(prompt1)
lb $v1, %lo(prompt1)($v0)
```

The same, of course, can be done with storing.

So, if you need to access a variable just once, you can use the two-instruction sequences (first of the two being `lui`) to read or write it. If you need the actual address for something (e.g. if you want to pass it to, say, `printf`), then you need to use `la`. If you need both, use `la` and keep the address in the register for as long as you need/can. So, there you go, the advantages and disadvantages.